# Resourse/py file in labelimg directory

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am installing labelimg on windows through anaconda but notice that the resource.py file is missing in the libs folder. Anyone who knows where i can find it?
labelimg directory is this  https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

Answer (score 0):

Read the installation instructions for Windows on the github repo you linked.  You need to use `pyrcc5` to create the `lib/resources.py` file from the `resources.qrc` file using the command:

```
pyrcc5 -o libs/resources.py resources.qrc
```